# DirectCast(sender, Control).ID Not working in Vb 2008

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I need to know the name of the object that i have just clicked on vb 2010 i can do it with DirectCast(sender, Control).ID , however i need to do this is 2008 and the .ID doesn't exist in 2008

I need the Equivalent of

```
lblPatient.Text = DirectCast(sender, Control).ID
```

'writen in vb 2010 visual web deveoper

For vb 2008

Code

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Public Class FormRm3A
    Dim Labels(40) As Label
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim Y As Integer
    Private Sub FormArrayTest_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim i As Integer

        i = 1
        For Me.Y = 1 To 5
            For Me.X = 1 To 8
                'creates new textbox
                Labels(i) = New Label()
                'set its properties
                Labels(i).Width = 50
                Labels(i).Height = 35
                Labels(i).Left = X * 49
                Labels(i).Top = 30 + (Y * 34)
                Labels(i).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                'add control to current form
                Me.Controls.Add(Labels(i))
                If Clicky = True Then
                    AddHandler Labels(i).Click, AddressOf Label1_Click
                End If
                i = i + 1
            Next X
        Next Y

        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim Subject As String
        Dim StaffInitials As String
        For Session = 1 To 40
            Try
                con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RoomBookingSystem.My.MySettings.Database1ConnectionString1").ConnectionString
                Dim SessionParm As New SqlParameter("Session", Session)
                SessionParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                con.Open()
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.Parameters.Add(SessionParm)
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Subject, StaffInitials FROM PermanantBooking WHERE (Week = 'A') AND(Room = 'Rm3') AND (Session = @Session)"
                Dim lrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While lrd.Read()

                    Subject = Convert.ToString((lrd("Subject").trim))
                    StaffInitials = Convert.ToString((lrd("StaffInitials").trim))

                    Labels(Session).Text = Subject & "" & vbNewLine & StaffInitials
                End While
                'Catch ex As Exception
                ' MsgBox("" & ex.Message)
                'here if there is an error it will go here (can use Msgbox or lable)
            Finally
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
                con.Close()
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim objectID As String
    objectID = DirectCast(sender, Control).ToString
    Day = 
    Period = X
    FormMakeBookingDetails.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET 3.5 already has [this property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)(actually `Control.Id` exists since 1.1)), so your code should work without a problem.

Can you show the complete code and exception?

**Edit**:

Since you have mentioned that you're using  visual web deveoper i've mistakenly assumed that you are using ASP.NET. Actually you're using Winforms. There is no `Id` property in Winforms unlike ASP.NET. Maybe you want to use the [`Name` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name.aspx) instead(available since 1.1).

Comment: myControl.ID and Control.ID both are not excepted

Comment: i think the problem is to do with that the label I am using is a control array of label(i), therefore there are multiple possible labels that could have been clicked , hence why i need to find it using the _sender_  added code

Comment: @WillPeckham: Both of your comments are not elucidative. Can you show the complete event handler of your labels. Btw, a `Label` does not have a click-event on serverside.

Comment: i use the `AddHandler Labels(i).Click, AddressOf Label1_Click` ... and it works if a labels is clicked it runs the subroutine

Comment: @WillPeckham: Since you have mentioned that you're using  visual web deveoper i've mistakenly assumed that you are using ASP.NET. Actually you're using Winforms. You should tag it accordingly. Edited my answer.

Comment: my tags are vb.net and visual-studio-2008 i have not tagged visual web developer however i have mentioned that i can sucessfuly writen in vb 2010 visual web deveoper

Comment: @WillPeckham: I'm not sure that you've recognized that i've edited my answer. In general you should always tag the technology(the IDE is not important but the framework version), so ASP.NET, WPF or Winforms.